# CakePHP Hash class with method extract/combine

Tags: cakephp, hash, extract

What is solution of extract to array

I have array:

```
$arr = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'name' => 'Value 1'
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'name' => 'Value 2'
    )
);
```

I would like get results like this:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Value 1
    [key2] => Value 2
)
```

In Cake 2.2 and lower works by `Set::extract('{\w+}.name', $arr)` but when I would like use Hash by `Hash::extract($arr, '{\w+).name')` the results not corectly (also `Hash::extract($arr, '{s}.name')` return incorect.

How do this using new Hash class?

Comment: I just tried that same example in my cakephp installation and worked fine using the Hash class and '{s}.name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a follow up on [@Anil kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645066/anil-kumar)'s answer

in case one of your result set returns an empty array, this would prevent an undefined index break:

```
$arr = Hash::map($arr, '', function($newArr) {
          return Hash::get($newArr, 'name');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$arr = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'name' => 'Value 1'
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'name' => 'Value 2'
    )
);

$arr = Hash::map($arr, '', function($newArr) {
    return $newArr['name'];
});
```

Now `$arr` will be:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Value 1
    [key2] => Value 2
)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `Hash` class was to be better!?

Comment: not getting you ? do you want to consider it in performance wise ?

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
    function admin_get_city() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $country_id = $this->request->data['Company']['country_id'];
    $city_id = $this->Company->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Company.country_id' => $country_id)));
    $cities_id = Hash::extract($city_id, '{n}.Company.city_id'); /*         * Hash::extract will Extarct language_id from array* */
    $this->set('city', $this->City->find('list', array('conditions' => array('City.country_id' => $country_id))));
}
```